# Is it a sombre note, or a sober note?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Should I talk about a "sombre note", or a "sober note"?

Google NGrams gives a roughly equal frequency for sombre, somber, or sober notes. Onelook doesn't give definitions for either a sombre note or a sober note.

I want to say

> On a more ___ note, I went on an English-language group tour of the "House of Sharing", a nursing home and museum for WWII "comfort women".

and I'm worried I'm choosing the wrong word merely because "sombre" and "sober" sound similar to each other.

Comment: Looking at examples from google books and/or Oxford Dictionary doesn’t help? Look at other uses of the two words besides just with ‘note’.

Comment: @Clare as mentioned in the question, I checked the frequency of the two alternatives using Google NGrams. I don't expect "sombre note" and "sober note" to have different meanings - I expect them to have the same intended meaning, and wish to check whether they are are valid or invalid phrases. You ask about Oxford Dictionary, but I already checked Onelook, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Either word could work. Depends what you’re contrasting this new tone with, drunkenness or hilarity.

Comment: **They mean different things!!**

Comment: As Hot Licks says, you need to decide what meaning you wish to convey and then choose that word.

Comment: Two references discussed in the question, and I'm told to "include the research". Ridiculous.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - "Include research", in this case, means "Include the dictionary definitions you are referencing."

Comment: @HotLicks I included all of the dictionary definitions of "sombre note" and "sober note" that OneLook had.

Comment: Did you include the relevant definitions of "sober" and "sombre"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both expressions are essentially cheap transitions when what follows is more serious than what went before and some other strategy, say, beginning a new paragraph, isn't an option. "Somber" still carries connotations of darkness and gloom, while "sober" evokes its opposite state after too much lager. If you have to use the construction, I'd just go for "serious" and be done with it.

Comment: How is a transition "cheap"?

Comment: When a writer can't think of any other way to get from light and lovely A to doom and gloom B.